# POST from AngularJS to Django API to obtain JWT and returning a 405 error

Tags: angularjs, django, http, post, jwt

i'm getting this 405 when i do a POST to get the token in the endpoint that supposed accepts POST requests.

I'm using rest_framework and rest_framework_jwt

Endpoint:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from rest_framework_jwt.views import obtain_jwt_token
from rest_framework_jwt.views import refresh_jwt_token
from rest_framework_jwt.views import verify_jwt_token

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^api/api-token-auth/', obtain_jwt_token),
    url(r'^api/api-token-verify/', verify_jwt_token),
    url(r'^api/api-token-refresh/', refresh_jwt_token),

]
```

AngularJS POST:

```
$scope.login = function () {

          $http.post('api/api-token-auth/',
              {
                'username': $scope.username,
                'password': $scope.password
              })
              .success(function (response) {
                $scope.logged = true;
                $scope.jwt = response.token;
                console.log(response.token);
                store.set('token', response.token);
              },function (response) {
                 $scope.logged = false;
                 console.log(response);
              });
        }
```

I'm getting the same error when doing the POST in Postman

Comment: Can you post your views.py, serializers.py, models.py and settings.py (the DRF configuration part), and the error message you receive in the client form the response? HTTP 405 error means method not allowed, so it may be an authentication/authorization problem set default settings or somewhere. Either way, having more information would help debug it.

Comment: You'll usually see a 405 in DRF when a request makes it to a view but has no method handler.  I would check to make sure that the request is going to the view you think it is by replacing it in the URL conf with a custom view.  I see that your URL patterns lack a "$" at the end, which might be causing the request to go to an unexpected view.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem, in my routes i had this for AngularJS routes:

```
url(r'^(?P<path>.*)/$', IndexView.as_view()),
```

So i changed to:

```
url(r'^/$', IndexView.as_view()),
```

And it worked